# Quickselect using a median-of-median-of-three partitioning

Tags: quickselect

What is the asymptotic running time of quickselect, using a median-of-median-of-three partitioning strategy? I feel that it should be the same as normal quick select and quicksort except the fact that the worst case gets mitigated significanlty. Am i right or is there more to it?